# I need to get the column names from a CSV file in SSIS

Tags: csv, ssis

I have an SSIS process that runs an R program, the R program exports its results into a CSV file.  Each time the R program is run the data in the CSV changes; the names of the columns and the number of columns changes.  The name of the CSV file stays constant.

What I need to do is read the names of the columns from this CSV file so I can dynamically create a table to store the data. Any suggestions on how to read the column names from the SSIS process?  I'm not a C# programmer so if the solution is a script task please provide a fairly detailed example

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SSIS is not going to be a good solution candidate. You'd basically be building disposable packages per run.

Comment: Yes I did, see my response to my question

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this to work with the help of a colleague (Thanks Connor), basically it opens the CSV and reads in the first line as long as the file is not empty.   I will now use this to dynamically generate a SQL CREATE TABLE Script

string path = @"C:\Users\ruschd\Documents\Medal Expectancy-MultiCompetitor\WinterSports_ratings_history_filter.csv";

```
        var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(path));
        string firstLine = null;
        List<string> colNames = new List<string>();


        if (!reader.EndOfStream)
          firstLine = reader.ReadLine();
            colNames.AddRange(firstLine.Split(','));

            MessageBox.Show(colNames[0].ToString());  // this is here to show that it is working, I'll loop thru the list to create the SQL

        reader.Close();
```

Comment: We also need to add a namespace to make above piece of code work.

Comment: using System.Collections.Generic;